# If $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(a_n\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2)=1$, then $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{(3n)}a_n=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2)=1$, prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{(3n)}a_n=1$.

Since $a_n^2\geqslant0$, if$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\to M,a_n\to 0, $then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2)=0$, it's contradictory to $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2)=1.$

So I conclude $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\to+\infty$, then I get 
$a_n\sim\frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2}\to 0$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{(3n)}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(3n)}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{3n}-\sqrt[3]{3(n-1)}}{a_n^2}$(according to $Stolz~theorem$)

However, I have no idea how to continue it, I sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the limit of $$[\sqrt[3]{3n}a_n]^2  \displaystyle\frac{\sqrt[3]{3n}-\sqrt[3]{3n-3}}{a_n^2} $$.

Comment: You should have made some mistake,for the limit cannot be negative.  Hint:$\sqrt[3]{3n}-\sqrt[3]{3n-3}=\frac{3n-(3n-3)}{**}$

Comment: I understand that the two factors approach the same limit, provided that either one of them exists. How does one show the provision, though? If not going through this route, how do you draw the conclusion?

Comment: @Hans You are right.I am sorry that I just forgot the condition of Stolz theorem. This is a big flaw. I think maybe the answer below is the only one.

Comment: Actually, I do not see how @Maddy's reasoning leads to the result. Do you care to explain?

Comment: @Hans $s_n/\sqrt[3]{3n} \rightarrow 1$ and $s_n\sim\frac{1}{a_n}$

Answer (score 6):

You are almost there. Consider $s_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2$.
We have $$\lim s_{n+1}/s_n=1+\lim(s_{n+1}-s_n)/s_n=1+\lim a_{n+1}^2/s_n=1.$$
Also, 
$$\lim s_{n+1}^3-s_n^3=\lim (s_{n+1}^2+s_{n+1}s_n+s_n^2)a_{n+1}^2=\lim (1+s_n/s_{n+1}+(s_n/s_{n+1})^2)(s_{n+1}a_{n+1})^2=3.$$
Thus, $\lim s_n^3/3n=1$. As $\lim_n a_ns_n=1$, $\lim_n\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3n}a_n}=\lim_n \frac{s_n}{\sqrt[3]{3n}}\frac{1}{a_ns_n}=1$. The result follows immediately.

Comment: Could you please explain the last sentence, and which averaging process leads to the final result?

Comment: @Did: Do you care to answer my question in my last comment? Maddy is not responding.

Comment: @Hans Which averaging step the OP is alluding to is unclear to me (and the one I can imagine leads to a wrong argument since a divergent sequence can converge in Cesaro sense) but the final step itself $s_n^3/3n\to1\implies a_n\sqrt[3]{3n}\to1$ is indeed direct since $a_ns_n\to1$.